# Why do processes on Mac not add up to total physical memory?

Tags: macos, memory, osx-lion, macbook-pro, ps

Running `ps -ax -O 'rss user %mem` should summon all the processes that are currently contributing to either Active or Wired , in the Mac definitions of

*"Active + Wired + Inactive + Free = Total Physical Memory" , right?*

**Activity Monitor** was showing high **Active** mem usage and hand-counting showed low numbers, so I re-counted with the below awk script.

Note the Activity Monitor screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckkT.png) for 'Active' and 'Wired'. At the time of capture, 'root' processes show ~377MiB and the not-root total ~1805MiB is close.

```
total: root  376632 KiB, and  active  1805476 KiB , percent :  51.9
% root  8.4
% active  43.5
```

[image: screenshot]

However, closing Chrome makes the problem clearer. I have an Activity Monitor screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBL9H.png) , with script output. Here, neither **Active** nor **Wired** memory matches.

```
total: root  365968 KiB, and  active  643880 KiB , percent :  23.6
% root  8.2
% active  15.4
```

[image: screenshot]

**mem_count.sh:**

```
 3 ps -axmc -O 'rss user %mem' | awk '
 4 
 5 BEGIN { 
 6     root = 0 ; active = 0 ; percent_root = 0.0 ;
 7     percent_active = 0.0  ; percent = 0.0 ; 
 8 } 
 9 
10 { 
11 percent += $4
12 if ( $3 == "root")  {  
13     root += $2 
14     percent_root  += $4 ; 
15 } 
16 else {  
17     active += $2  
18     percent_active  += $4 ; 
19 } 
20 
21 } 
22 END {
23     print "total: root ", root, "KiB, and  active ", active , "KiB , percent : ", percent  ; 
24     print "% root " , percent_root      
25     print "% active " , percent_active    
26 }'
```

sample output

```
$ ps -axmc -O 'rss user %mem'
PID    RSS USER             %MEM   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
37 160964 root              3.8   ??  Ss    20:22.92 mds 
...
```

This is causing a bit of a headache. 
Image Ref:

Comment: You might want to check out `top`. It's different from its Linux counterpart and does support programmatic output parsing like e.g. [here](http://superuser.com/questions/281347/filtering-top-command-output/281654#281654).

Answer (score 0):

ps displays stats for **user processes** only. **It does not report stats about the kernel**. So, don't expect the memory reported by ps to ever add up to the total physical memory.

You also seem to have misunderstood some key concepts of unix-like operating systems and OSX memory management. I can't tell which exactly, but here

1. **root != kernel**: root is a user as well.
2. **wired memory != memory used by root processes**
3. **active memory != memory used by your processes**
4. **inactive memory does not work the way one may think**: It also includes memory from running processes. Read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/460658/why-os-x-use-swap-when-there-is-lots-of-inactive-memory/464561) which provides some insight on inactive memory.

The bottom line is that there is no trivial correlation between the aggregate memory statistics of the Activity Monitor and the memory usage statistics reported by ps.

Comment: That's true except when -a is used with -x . -A and -ax are supposed to be equivalent forms. But I'll do a sanity check!

Comment: Yea no difference. Thanks though.

Comment: @HeyWatchThis There's no line with PID 0 in your `ps` output. That'd be the kernel (compare Activity Monitor output).

Comment: @DanielBeck Exactly my point. ps does not report stats for the kernel (showing up as with pid 0 in Activity Monitor and other tools - e.g. top). Even if you explicitely ask for this process (ps -p 0), ps will not report anything.